# Delete files that are not included with `rsync --files-from`

Tags: rsync

I copy files to another location using `rsync` with the option `--files-from`. Sometimes, a file gets deleted and is not included in that list of files any more. I tried to use `--delete`, but that would not delete any files that are not in the list any more.

How could I delete the files using this approach?

---

The point is that I only want to copy all the PDF files, files that end in `.pdf`. I could do that with `--exclude` and `--include` but that would require me to exclude all files, then re-include sub-directories and the PDF files. I thought that using `find -name '*.pdf'` as input for `rsync --files-from` would be a more sensible approach, until I hit that delete issue above.

Comment: The combination of exclude and include is the standard, perfectly cromulent way to do it.