# rsync --delete is not working

Tags: rsync

OS is Debian 10, rsync version 3.1.3. I'm running rsync like this:

```
time rsync -ar --delete --info=progress2 --files-from=filelist.txt . /path/to/dest
```

This works to copy the files over, but doesn't delete anything that's been removed. (Either removed entirely from src, or in my case, removed from filelist.txt) That is a huge problem. The only workaround I have found is to simply nuke the entire destination and just copy everything over again, but this takes a huge amount of time and basically negates the point of using rsync in the first place.

Is this a bug? How do I get rsync to work properly, honoring the --delete flag like it's supposed to?

Edit:

For example:

- If filelist.txt cotains "foo" then /path/to/dest will contain "foo".
- If filelist.txt cotains "foo" and "bar" then /path/to/dest will contain "foo" and "bar".
- If filelist.txt cotains "foo", "bar", and "bat" then /path/to/dest will contain "foo", "bar", and "bat".
- etc

Assume "foo" "bar" "bat" etc are directories.

Comment: Is this the same as https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/138488/117549?

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "been removed".  Is a file removed only from the filesystem, or is it also removed from the filelist.txt?

Comment: Not the same, I have no file extension I'm trying to filter by.

Comment: /path/to/dest should contain only directories that are listed in filelist.txt. if filelist.txt is empty, /path/to/dest should be empty also. Trivial use case.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell rsync to delete the missing arguments:

```
rsync -arv --delete-missing-args --delete --info=progress2 --files-from=filelist.txt . /path/to/dest
```

- So if you delete the directory `foo` it will then also be deleted in `/path/to/dest` with `--delete-missing-args`.
- `foo` still needs to be listed in `filelist.txt`.
- the `--delete` argument is required to allow rsync to delete the files in the `foo` folder

Comment: In my case, foo will be present in src, but not present in filelist.txt. I want to keep foo around, but I no longer want it to sync to dest (and thus have it removed)

Comment: Instead of using filelist.txt - would making a hard- or symlinked copy of the directory (where you only keep the files you want to be synced) be an option?

Answer (score 0):

No. `rsync` will not delete files/ dirs just because the files list do not contain those file or it is empty.

if you are using `--files-from` it will try to sync only the files listed from source to destination.

It will not delete the files just because they are absent from files list passed to `--files-from`.

For --delete to work you need to use the actual source path .. like so

```
rsync -ar --delete path/to/src path/to/destination
```